# How to get predicted class labels in TensorFlow's MNIST example?

Tags: python, machine-learning, neural-network, tensorflow, data-science

I am new to Neural Networks and went through the MNIST example for beginners.

I am currently trying to use this example on another dataset from Kaggle that does not have test labels.

If I run the model on the test data set without corresponding labels and therefore unable to compute the accuracy like in the MNIST example, I would like to be able to see the predictions. Is it possible to access observations and their predicted labels somehow and print them out nicely?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you just need to evaluate your output-tensor as stated in the tutorial:

```
accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_prediction, "float"))
print(sess.run(accuracy, feed_dict={x: mnist.test.images, y_: mnist.test.labels}))
```

To get the output of a tensor see the [docs](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/framework.html#Tensor):

> After the graph has been launched in a session, the value of the Tensor can be computed by passing it to Session.run(). t.eval() is a shortcut for calling tf.get_default_session().run(t).

If you want to get predictions rather than accuracy, you need to evaluate your ouput tensor `y` in the same way:

```
print(sess.run(y, feed_dict={x: mnist.test.images}))
```

Comment: when I try print(sess.run(y, feed_dict={x: mnist.test.images})), I get: TypeError: unhashable type: 'numpy.ndarray'. Are other people seeing this or does it work for them?

Answer (score 1):

```
prediction=tf.argmax(y,1)
print prediction.eval(feed_dict={x: mnist.test.images}).
```

For more details, check out https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/97