# Get Predicted result from tensorflow

Tags: python, python-2.7, machine-learning, neural-network, tensorflow

I am doing my first tensor flow example with following code.

```
train_x,train_y,test_x,test_y=create_feature_sets_and_labels('pro.txt','neg.txt')
n_nodes_hl1 = 1500
n_nodes_hl2 = 1500
n_nodes_hl3 = 1500

n_classes = 2
batch_size = 100
hm_epochs = 7

x = tf.placeholder('float')
y = tf.placeholder('float')

hidden_1_layer = {'f_fum':n_nodes_hl1,
              'weight':tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([len(train_x[0]), n_nodes_hl1])),
              'bias':tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_nodes_hl1]))}

hidden_2_layer = {'f_fum':n_nodes_hl2,
              'weight':tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_nodes_hl1, n_nodes_hl2])),
              'bias':tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_nodes_hl2]))}

hidden_3_layer = {'f_fum':n_nodes_hl3,
              'weight':tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_nodes_hl2, n_nodes_hl3])),
              'bias':tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_nodes_hl3]))}

output_layer = {'f_fum':None,
            'weight':tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_nodes_hl3, n_classes])),
            'bias':tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_classes])),}


def neural_network_model(data):

    l1 = tf.add(tf.matmul(data,hidden_1_layer['weight']), hidden_1_layer['bias'])
    l1 = tf.nn.relu(l1)

    l2 = tf.add(tf.matmul(l1,hidden_2_layer['weight']), hidden_2_layer['bias'])
    l2 = tf.nn.relu(l2)

    l3 = tf.add(tf.matmul(l2,hidden_3_layer['weight']), hidden_3_layer['bias'])
    l3 = tf.nn.relu(l3)

    output = tf.matmul(l3,output_layer['weight']) + output_layer['bias']

    return output

def train_neural_network(x):
    prediction = neural_network_model(x)

    cost = tf.reduce_mean( tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(prediction,y) )
    optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate=0.001).minimize(cost)

    with tf.Session() as sess:
            sess.run(tf.initialize_all_variables())

            for epoch in range(hm_epochs):
                    epoch_loss = 0
                    i=0
                    while i < len(train_x):
                            start = i
                            end = i+batch_size
                            batch_x = np.array(train_x[start:end])
                            batch_y = np.array(train_y[start:end])

                            _, c = sess.run([optimizer, cost], feed_dict={x: batch_x,
                                                          y: batch_y})
                            epoch_loss += c
                            i+=batch_size

                    print('Epoch', epoch+1, 'completed out of',hm_epochs,'loss:',epoch_l$                correct = tf.equal(tf.argmax(prediction, 1), tf.argmax(y, 1))
            accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct, 'float'))
            print(y)
            print('Accuracy:',accuracy.eval({x:test_x, y:test_y}))


train_neural_network(x)
```

It give me accuracy on test data. 
What i want is to give an input sentence to my train model and it returns me predicted label.

i tried following form this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34060332/how-to-get-predicted-class-labels-in-tensorflows-mnist-example)

```
#with same length as lexicon               
input = [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.$ 
output = sess.run(y, feed_dict={x :input})
```

it gives me following error.

```
You must feed a value for placeholder tensor 'Placeholder_1' with dtype float
     [[Node: Placeholder_1 = Placeholder[dtype=DT_FLOAT, shape=[], _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"]()]]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first argument for `session.run()` should be tensor you want to get.

In your case it should be `prediction` tensor (so you need to return it from your `train_neural_network`). Apply argmax to it to obtain predicted label.

Comment: **worked:** output= sess.run(tf.argmax(prediction,1),feed_dict={x: input})

Comment: I would recommend replacing `tf.argmax` with `numpy.argmax(output)` or moving `tf.argmax` to graph definition stage (`neaural_network_model` function). Otherwise it will add new argmax node every time you run your line of code.

Comment: can i get accuracy of predicted output?