# TensorFlow: evaluate a single input with sess.run

Tags: tensorflow

I've trained a network in TensorFlow using a session

```
sess.run([train_op, loss], feed_dict=feed_dict)
```

What's the simplest way to give the session an input of **a single** data row and print the output?

I've tried (many variations of)

```
sess.run(print_function, data_row)
```

But I get the result

```
You must feed a value for placeholder tensor 'Placeholder_1'
with dtype int32 and shape [<batch size>]
```

Comment: What are `print_function` and `data_row`? There are several answers to this question on stackoverflow.

Comment: @NickBecker Data row is one row from the csv file as an array. print_function is a placeholder that returns a default value

Comment: Does this answer your question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34060332/how-to-get-predicted-class-labels-in-tensorflows-mnist-example

Comment: @NickBecker No, because x,y_ are placeholders that expect a tensor with more than one row

Comment: If you haven't figured it out yet, I'd suggest posting a reproducible example of your code (perhaps on the MNIST data). Yes, the placeholders expect arrays with specific shapes -- but you can set one of the dimensions to None (which would allow you to pass one observation).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assumption - Your first dimension represents the number of inputs (as is the case in most offical examples)

I'd suggest making the first dimension of the placeholder as `None` to have the option of passing any number of batches. Have a look at this tutorial for an example - http://learningtensorflow.com/lesson4/

Quoting from this tutorial,

> The first dimension of the placeholder is `None`, meaning we can have any number of rows. The second dimension is fixed at 3, meaning each row needs to have three columns of data.

It's also well documented in the official documentation in https://www.tensorflow.org/resources/faq#how_do_i_build_a_graph_that_works_with_variable_batch_sizes.